# What are these orange clusters growing on my soil?

Tags: trees, houseplants, lemons

Went to water my lemon tree and found these orange clusters growing on my soil. It’s been in the 90’s all week, so I’m thinking the heat and moisture triggered this orange cluster. Maybe a sort of fungi?[image]

Comment: Have these only just appeared? So far, no evidence of stems or stalks, so yes, its  likely fungal, but without stems and seeing under  the caps, hard to ID for sure. If they develop more/change their appearance, its worth adding another photo.

Comment: Photograph a day later - then we can see if it is a slime mould.

Comment: Yes they just appeared yesterday. I will add another picture

Answer (score 1):

[Tremella mesenterica (Witches’ butter)](https://education.mdc.mo.gov/discover-nature/field-guide/witches%E2%80%99-butter)

> Description: Small, yellow, irregularly lobed, gelatinous masses.
> Grows on dead deciduous wood. Year-round. Fruiting body irregularly
> lobed, brainlike; sulfur yellow to pale yellow; texture gelatinous.
> Spore print yellowish. Spores magnified are oval, elliptical, smooth.

They can look really different. Compare to an image [search](https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=Witches%20Butter&form=HDRSC2&first=1&tsc=ImageHoverTitle).